# Trying to pass variable state to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm trying to pass a variable Boolean "state" (true/false) to a server from an HTML file.

```
<script>
    $("#aaa").click(function () {
        $(this).hide('slow');
        $("#bam").html(shay + " arrived ").hide().show(700);
    childName = true;
        counter++;
        if (counter > 12) {
            $("#bam").html("All have arrived").hide().show(700);

        }
    });
</script>
```

I have multiple instances of this function for each kid arriving to school. The name of the kid's variable equals to true upon clicking his name. What I'd like to do is send these variables' Boolean state to a server, so I'll be able to remotely know what's each kid's "state". Is there a way to do it with jQuery's Post method? If not, what is the most simple way? Thanks!

Comment: yes, jQuery.post would be the correct way to post data to the server

Comment: Yes, you can POST it to the server that way, but do you even have a backend on the server receiving the data?

Comment: Yes, I'm using my university server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do

```
<script>
    $("#aaa").click(function () {
        $(this).hide('slow');
        $("#bam").html(shay + " arrived ").hide().show(700);
    childName = true;
     $.post("url",
        {
          childStatus: childName,
        },
        function(status){ // return from server

        });
        counter++;
        if (counter > 12) {
            $("#bam").html("All have arrived").hide().show(700);

        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can post any thing to server with jquery post method like bellow example:

```
$("#aaa").click(function () {
   $(this).hide('slow');
   $("#bam").html(shay + " arrived ").hide().show(700);
   childName = true;
   counter++;
   $.post("destination.asp", {childStatus: childName}, function(result){
        // do any thing
    });
    if (counter > 12) {
        $("#bam").html("All have arrived").hide().show(700);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have an id for each child. And add an event listener which sends data to server. For example,

**HTML:**

```
<button id="id_001" class="childBtn">Arrived</div>
<button id="id_002" class="childBtn">Arrived</div>
<button id="id_003" class="childBtn">Arrived</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".childBtn").click(function(){
  $.post('http://yourserver.com/api', { childId : $(this).attr('id')},
    function(data, status) {
      //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    }
});
```

I hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, please check out the documentation for .ajax(): [official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Could look something like this:

```
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'your-endpoint-url', // the endpoint for the call
      data: childName,
      success: function(response){ 
         console.log('AJAX success: ' + response);
         // maybe do something else here ...
      },
      error: function(error, status, xhr){
         console.log('AJAX error: ' + error);
         console.log('STATUS: ' + status + ', XHR: ' + xhr);
      }
   });
```

Side note: you say you have multiple instances of this function; then why assign the click function to a DOM element ('#aaa'), rather than doing this through a (e.g.) class selector (give your schookid-rows a css class '.schoolkid' and assign the click function via the class selector)